# ConnectionRefusedError(10061 ) while instaling request module

Tags: python

I'm new to python, when I tried installing requests module im getting the following error. Could someone help me on this.

```
C:\Program Files\Scripts>pip install requests
Collecting requests
        Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/requests/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from version
s: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```